# how to have 2 comments_template() in one post

Tags: comments, comments-template

I have an issue in my new theme.
**my website is about Education** for teachers and students. every post belongs to one teacher that students can talk to her/him via comments.
now, i want to add a special thing to any post. i want to have two comments_template() in one post with **pills** (bootstrap). in one, student can just **ask their questions** but in another, they can **do review and rating**.
in fact i need to use different comments_template file for every one.

**but the problem is:** by adding two comments_template to one post, every comment will be displayed in another part too. but i want to just to be displayed in its part (pill).

so can you help me in this case???
i really need it. thanks y friends

**UPDATE:**

for example, i added these codes to the `single.php` to have 2 `comment_template()`. one for discussing and another for rating to the teacher. but when i comment in one part, it will be shown in another too. and i want to use different `comment_tamplate()` for avery part:

```
<div class="row container-fluid profile_nazar" style=" margin: 0 5% 30px 5% !important; margin-bottom: 20px; border: 1px solid #ddd; box-shadow: 0 0 6px #ccc;">

    <ul class="nav-pills profile_pills">
        <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#pill1">Talk</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#pill2">Rate</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div style="width:100%; height:400px; overflow-y: scroll;">
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="pill1" class="tab-pane fade in active" style="margin: 20px;">
                <?php comments_template(); ?>
            </div>
            <div id="pill2" class="tab-pane fade" style="margin: 20px;">
                <?php comments_template(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share some code you already have it will be easier to help then?

Comment: @GregWiniarski  i updated my question, my friend.

Comment: This is a bit complicated, you would need to register different comment types and make sure each comment_template() is saving and listing the comment with correct comment_type, that being said i am afraid i am not sure how to code it, you would need to dig into the WP source code i suppose.

Comment: @GregWiniarski  yes my friend. i also think it is complicated. but for solving that, i want to create another `post type` and make a post for every teacher to have discussion with her/him students. but the issue is: i want to add a button in the profile page as `"talk to your teacher"` but i can not use `the_permalink();` for that, because another post for that teacher belongs to another `post type`. how can i automatically find that post permalink (in another post type). consider that in those two posts (different post type), the teacher is `post author`.

Comment: @sh.dehnavi, you can use `the_permalink()` to get the permalink of any post types. You just need to use the correct post ID - `the_permalink( 123 )`.

Comment: @SallyCJ Hi my friend again. please check my answer to this question.

Comment: Ok, @sh.dehnavi. Just go with what works best in your specific case, and if you need further assistance, you can always post another question. :) Cheers.

Comment: @SallyCJ thanks my friend really. but i have an important question that i have done it but a little thing. would you help me again? [my question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/321934/how-to-count-rows-of-table-in-the-content-if-it-contains-special-string-in)

Comment: I would've posted an answer [there](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/321934/how-to-count-rows-of-table-in-the-content-if-it-contains-special-string-in), if it wasn't closed, @sh.dehnavi. Nonetheless, try [this](https://pastebin.com/9vtHL9yd).

Comment: @SallyCJ my friend, please put your answer in the [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/323070/how-to-count-the-table-rows-that-contain-special-string) to can i accept it, so you can get the more `reputation` :)

Comment: @SallyCJ and please see the **update #1** in [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/323070/how-to-count-the-table-rows-that-contain-special-string) and help me about that.

Comment: It's alright @sh.dehnavi. And please choose the proper site when asking your question - when in doubt, check [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), or try on Stack Overflow. Have a good day.

Comment: @SallyCJ, Hi my friend again. i did not know that. sorry sorry. but would you help me in this [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/323094/an-issue-for-select-query-in-wordpress) please

Comment: @SallyCJ my friend i ask my question in the following site. Please please see that: [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53804389/issue-in-select-query-in-wp-count-the-number-of-times-a-string-appears-in-db?noredirect=1#comment94459196_53804389) if i did not need that, i never insisted a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i could not solve the main problem (two comments_template() in one post) but i created a `new post_type` for "talk to teacher" part and so we will create a post for every teacher in that post type and put the link of that post in `teacher's profile page`. by clicking on that link, students will go to new post that can just comment for the teacher and talk with her/him.
.

so by the following code, we can find that post in the `new post_type` to be used in the `profile page`:
consider: also in the new post, the `author` is the same.

```
<?php
$author_id = get_the_author_meta( 'ID' );
$post_ids = get_posts(array( 'fields' => 'ids', 'author' => $author_id, 'post_type' => 'talk', ));
$num = 0;
foreach($post_ids as $post_id) :        
    echo "<a href='". get_permalink( $post_id )."'>talk to your teacher</a></br>";
    // the following condition, consider the last post that has created for the teacher to talk with students 
    $num = $num + 1;
    if ($num >= 1){
        break;
    }
endforeach;
?>
```