# How to add/update post meta to use in query?

Tags: post-meta, comment-meta, rating

I found a rating system that users can rate the post when commenting.  Every thing is good but I want to **use the average rating of posts** to sort them to users based on average rating (in fact **be able to query**).
I don't know how I can do that???
The rating_key and rating_value will be saved in `wp_commentmeta` table but I want to save the average rating value of every post in `wp_postmeta` to be able to query posts based on it.
I can get average rating of every post but **I do not how to save and update it in `wp_postmeta` as a special key** (like avg_post):

```
<?php
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_commentmeta WHERE meta_key = 'rating' ");
foreach($results as $result){
    $rate = $result->meta_value;
    $sum +=$rate;
}
$res = $sum/count($results);
$res = number_format((float)$res,1,'.','');
?>
```

.

**Update:**

I created the new field in my custom comment template so:

```
add_action('comment_form_logged_in_after','additional_fields');
add_action('comment_form_after_fields','additional_fields');
function additional_fields(){
?>
<p class="comment-form-rating">
    <label for="rating">Rating</label>
    <span class="starRting">
    <?php
        for($i=5;$i>=1;$i--)
            echo '<input id="rating'.$i.'" type="radio" name="rating" value="'.$i.'"><label for="rating'.$i.'"></label>';
    ?>
    </span>
</p>
```

Then I saved the rating values in `comment_meta` :

```
function save_comment_meta_phone($comment_id){
    if(!empty($_POST['rating']))
        $rating = sanitize_text_field($_POST['rating']);
        add_comment_meta($comment_id,'rating',$rating);
}
add_action('comment_post','save_comment_meta_phone');
```

**But I need** a function to calculate the average rating of every post and save it in `post_meta` via a key.

Comment: You can save that meta (`avg_post`) when the `rating` meta is saved. But where's the code which saves the `rating` meta?

Comment: @SallyCJ i added a field to the comment for rating but the rating meta will be save for every comment in wp_commentmeta. but i want to add average rating as a meta to wp_postmeta for every post to be able to query. did you get what i mean?

Comment: @SallyCJ i updated the question. thanks for helping

Comment: Ok thanks for the update. And I did get what you mean - you want to save the average rating whenever a comment is rated. Am I correct?

Comment: @SallyCJ yes. i want to save the average rating (as a value) in wp_postmeta table (data base) for every post with a special key. because i want to display my posts based on the average rating for my users to know which one in better. i want to use that meta_key in query to display posts. OK?

Comment: Yes, OK. Check my answer.

Comment: So, have you tried the code?

Comment: my fiend, i am trying but i see _warning: Division by zero_ when i want to display the number of rating. because the count is zero. please see the first box code in my question. i got the warning for this line: `$res = $sum/count($results);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function, which you'd add to the theme's `functions.php` file, to update the average post rating which is saved in a private meta named `_avg_rating` (but you can of course rename it) — private meta has their name starting with an underscore (`_`):

```
function update_post_avg_rating( $comment_id, $post_id = 0 ) {
    if ( ! $post_id ) {
        if ( ! $comment = get_comment( $comment_id ) ) {
            return false;
        }

        $post_id = $comment->comment_post_ID;
    }

    // Retrieve the ID of all rating comments in post $post_id.
    $ids = get_comments( [
        'meta_key' => 'rating',
        'post_id'  => $post_id,
        'fields'   => 'ids',
        'status'   => 'all',
    ] );

    // Calculate the average rating (using a custom MySQL query).
    $avg = 0;
    if ( ! empty( $ids ) ) {
        global $wpdb;

        $avg = $wpdb->get_var( "
            SELECT AVG(meta_value + 0) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}commentmeta
            WHERE meta_key = 'rating'
                AND comment_id IN (" . implode( ',', $ids ) . ")
        " );
    }

    // Update the average rating.
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_avg_rating', $avg );
}
```

Then call the function after you saved the post rating, like so:

```
function save_comment_meta_phone( $comment_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['rating'] ) ) {
        $rating = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['rating'] );

        // Save the post rating.
        add_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'rating', $rating );

        // Then update the average rating.
        update_post_avg_rating( $comment_id );
    }
}
```

Btw, you may want to rename the `save_comment_meta_phone()` function to `save_comment_meta_rating`?.. (just a suggestion)

And in the `update_post_avg_rating()` code, in the `get_comments()` call, you can set the `status` to `approve` if you want to include only *approved* post ratings.

### UPDATE

*Removed, but you can always view the answer's revisions.*

### UPDATE #2

*Removed, but you can always view the answer's revisions.*

### UPDATE #3

Hopefully these help you in *using* the `_avg_rating` meta:

1. To show the average rating of an individual post, you can use `get_post_meta()` like so:

   ```
   $avg_rating = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_avg_rating', true );
   $avg_rating = $avg_rating ? number_format_i18n( $avg_rating, 1 ) : 0;
   echo $avg_rating;
   ```
2. To sort posts by the `_avg_rating` meta, while still including posts that do *not* have the `_avg_rating` meta, you can use *keyed* `meta_query` like so:

   ```
   $q = new WP_Query( array(
       'post_type'  => 'post',
       'meta_query' => array(
           'relation'          => 'OR',
           'avg_rating_clause' => array(
               'key'     => '_avg_rating',
               'compare' => 'EXISTS',
               'type'    => 'DECIMAL',
           ),
           'avg_rating_clause2' => array(
               'key'     => '_avg_rating',
               'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
               'type'    => 'DECIMAL',
           ),
       ),
       'orderby'    => array(
           'avg_rating_clause2' => 'DESC',
           'date'               => 'DESC',
       ),
       //...
   ) );

   // Sample for displaying the posts.
   if ( $q->have_posts() ) {
       while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
           $q->the_post();

           $avg_rating = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_avg_rating', true );
           $avg_rating = $avg_rating ? number_format_i18n( $avg_rating, 1 ) : 0;

           the_title( '<h2>', ' (Avg. Rating: ' . $avg_rating . ')</h2>' );
       }
   }
   ```

   See [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) for more details on the `meta_query`.

Comment: my friend, thanks but we have two issue: 1- i want to display the number of ratings for every post, that is why, i tried to use that simple _SELECT_ . see this link [link] (http://s8.picofile.com/file/8345296742/0.png) but that select all all of rating value for all post. how can select the rating for every post id? (please see my first code box)

Comment: and another issue is: when i use query based on our _avg_rating key to display and sort the posts, the query does not display those posts that have not rating. did you get what i mean? i use this query `$args = array(
 'post_type' => 'post',
 'meta_key' => '_avg_rating',
 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
 'order' => 'DSC',
 );`

Comment: have you got what i mean?

Comment: The `update_post_avg_rating()` **is indeed calculating the average rating of a post, and that the average rating value is saved in a custom field named `_avg_rating`**. So I believe that has already answered the question - "*I need a function to calculate the average rating of every post and save it in post_meta via a key*".

Comment: yes my friend. you did that. thanks a lot and a lot. thanks over and over but if you can, tell me how to display and sort posts based on the `_avg_rating` and displaying even those posts dont have rating? (still nobody rate them).

Comment: Answer updated. All the best.

Comment: thanks a lot my friend. a lot and a lot. god with you

Comment: by the way, i updated my that question. `I found a way`. please see the `last comment` of the following question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/321397/how-to-have-2-comments-template-in-one-post

Comment: You're welcome. And apologize for my comment yesterday... I did *not* mean not to help you, but you don't need the "simple" `SELECT` query since you already have the function in the answer, which calculates the average post rating and save it in the post meta table. You've also seen how you can use the saved meta, via the "UPDATE #3" section in the answer - and it's not actually hard to display the meta value or sort posts using that value, right?

Comment: About that [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/321397/how-to-have-2-comments-template-in-one-post), I'll check it further tomorrow.

Comment: Hi my friend, did you check the [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/321397/how-to-have-2-comments-template-in-one-post) and the last comment?