# how to SELECT for the current post id?

Tags: comments, query

i am trying to get and count the values of a meta key (rating) and then calculate the sum. but the following code get **all of values** in `wp_commentmeta` table but i want to get **just for the current post**. how should i solve that?

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT meta_value FROM {$wpdb->prefix}commentmeta WHERE meta_key = 'rating' ");
foreach($results as $result){
    $rate = $result->meta_value;
    $sum +=$rate;
}
$res = $sum/count($results);
$res = number_format((float)$res,2,'.','');
```

and how to count the number of 5 star ratings (the special value) for the current post. the code:

```
$countstar = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT count(meta_value) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}commentmeta WHERE meta_key = 'rating' AND meta_value = '5'");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do that by joining data from wp_comments table as this table contains information about which comments belong to which posts

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare( "
    SELECT meta_value 
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}commentmeta 
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}comments ON {$wpdb->prefix}commentmeta.comment_id = {$wpdb->prefix}comments.comment_ID 
    WHERE comment_post_ID = %d AND meta_key = 'rating' ", get_the_ID() 
);
$results = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
```

Note that MySQL can sum the values for you, you do not need to do that using PHP.

UPDATED:

The number of 5 star ratings for current post you can count with the below query

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare( "
    SELECT count(meta_value) 
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}commentmeta 
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}comments ON {$wpdb->prefix}commentmeta.comment_id = {$wpdb->prefix}comments.comment_ID 
    WHERE comment_post_ID = %d AND meta_key = 'rating' AND meta_value = '5' ", get_the_ID() 
);
$wpdb->get_var( $sql );
```

although since you are iterating over the ratings in foreach loop anyway then inside the loop you can count 5 star ratings  without running a second query like this

```
$rating5 = 0;
foreach($results as $result){
    if( $result->meta_value == '5' ) {
        $rating5++;
    }
    $rate = $result->meta_value;
    $sum +=$rate;
}
```

Comment: thanks my friend a lot. but i do not need the sum because i need to `count($results)` too. i want to get the average. did you get what i mean?

Comment: ohh sorry i missed that, i updated my code, now after the `$results = ...` line you can use your foreach loop from the first post.

Comment: sure, no problem :)

Comment: would you help me in this issue too? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/321397/how-to-have-2-comments-template-in-one-post

Comment: oh my friend, how can do with this? it need just `meta_value = '5'` in this code and for every post id: `$countstar = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT count(meta_value) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}commentmeta WHERE meta_key = 'rating' AND meta_value = '5'");`

Comment: The code you posted will get a number of comments with rating = 5. Would you like it to count the number of 5 star ratings for the current post only? (as in the code in my reply)?

Comment: yes. it is another question. i want to count the number of 5 star ratings for the current post. would you help me and add an update to your answer? thanks

Comment: ok, i updated my answer.

Comment: thanks my friend. i updated the following issue:  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/321397/how-to-have-2-comments-template-in-one-post