# Show ranking based on post id

Tags: php

I created a rating for my site with this code, now it shows all the ratings for all posts and I want to show the number of ratings based on the post ID.

comment.php

```
<div class="custom-comments">
<div class="container">
    <?php
    $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_commentmeta WHERE meta_key = 'rating' ");
    foreach($results as $result){
        $rate = $result->meta_value;
        $sum +=$rate;
    }
    $res = $sum/count($results);
    $res = number_format((float)$res,1,'.','');
    ?>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7 pull-left">
        <div class="review-rating">
            <h2>Average Rating</h2>
            <?php
            for($i=0;5>$i;$i++){
            ?>
            <i class="<?php if(round($res)>$i) echo 'fa fa-star'; else echo 'fa fa-star-o'; ?>" ></i>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
            <span><?php echo $res ?> out of 5 star</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 pull-left">
    <div class="reviews-about">
        <label for="" class="reviews"><?php echo number_format(count($results)); ?> Reviews</label>
        
        <?php
        $countstar = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT count(meta_value) FROM wp_commentmeta WHERE meta_key = 'rating' AND meta_value = '5'");
        $total = count($results);
        $res = 100/$total;
        $avgstar = $countstar*$res;
        ?>
        <span class="star">5 Star</span>
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70"
            aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:<?php echo $avgstar; ?>%">
            <?php echo ($countstar != '0')?$countstar : ''; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        $countstar = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT count(meta_value) FROM wp_commentmeta WHERE meta_key = 'rating' AND meta_value = '4'");
        $total = count($results);
        $res = 100/$total;
        $avgstar = $countstar*$res;
        ?>
        <span class="star">4 Star</span>
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70"
            aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:<?php echo $avgstar; ?>%">
            <?php echo ($countstar != '0')?$countstar : ''; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        $countstar = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT count(meta_value) FROM wp_commentmeta WHERE meta_key = 'rating' AND meta_value = '3'");
        $total = count($results);
        $res = 100/$total;
        $avgstar = $countstar*$res;
        ?>
        <span class="star">3 Star</span>
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70"
            aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:<?php echo $avgstar; ?>%">
            <?php echo ($countstar != '0')?$countstar : ''; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        $countstar = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT count(meta_value) FROM wp_commentmeta WHERE meta_key = 'rating' AND meta_value = '2'");
        $total = count($results);
        $res = 100/$total;
        $avgstar = $countstar*$res;
        ?>
        <span class="star">2 Star</span>
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70"
            aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:<?php echo $avgstar; ?>%">
            <?php echo ($countstar != '0')?$countstar : ''; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        $countstar = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT count(meta_value) FROM wp_commentmeta WHERE meta_key = 'rating' AND meta_value = '1'");
        $total = count($results);
        $res = 100/$total;
        $avgstar = $countstar*$res;
        ?>
        <span class="star">1 Star</span>
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70"
            aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:<?php echo $avgstar; ?>%">
            <?php echo ($countstar != '0')?$countstar : ''; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to SELECT for the current post id?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/321539/how-to-select-for-the-current-post-id)

Comment: This appears to be a carbon copy of the question linked above. If your question is different from that one, please [edit] the question to specify what makes this question unique.

Comment: Hello, I fixed it, thank you for your help